# When deploying on pythonanywhere i followed all stepts but still get the default pythonanywhere page

Tags: django, wsgi, pythonanywhere, django-deployment

I did all the stepts from the documentation but still get the pythonanywhere default page, and I do not even know from where is coming since is not in my wsgi. Below is my wsgi, anyone has any clue? Thanks

```
import os
import sys

path = '/home/andercorobert/agile-project/app'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'agile.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Tried to do it several times and also did changes to virtualenv and so on.

Comment: See [https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DeployExistingDjangoProject/)